# Set App.xaml to a UserControl WPF (to connect Locator)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodellocator

#### Situation :

I'm currently trying to connect my `DataContext` to my `ViewModel`. I'm using `GalaSoftMvvmLight`.

But the fact is that I don't have a `Window` because I'll integrate this code in another program, which has a `Window`. So I just have `UserControl`.

#### Problem :

I don't know why, but I can't connect my `DataContext` in `UserControl`.

I get this error `{"Cannot find resource named 'Locator'. Resource names are case sensitive."}`

#### Question :

How can I connect properly my App.xaml resources to my View ? And if it's not possible without `Window`, how can I call `DataContext` with something like this

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    SOMETHING TO SET DATACONTEXT WITH BINDING !
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

### Here is my code :

#### App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="SOMETHING.App" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SOMETHING.ViewModel" StartupUri="ApplicationView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

#### ApplicationView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SOMETHING.View.ApplicationView"
         <!-- THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK -->
         DataContext="{Binding ApplicationVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <!-- THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK IF I SET <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" /> IN STYLE.XAML, BUT I CAN'T USE IT IN USERCONTROL PARAMETERS (LIKE ABOVE) -->
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
         <Label Content="{Binding Title}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### ViewModelLocator

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ApplicationViewModel>();
    }

    public ApplicationViewModel ApplicationVM
    {
        get { return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ApplicationViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the ViewModelLocator class defined? It the UserControl is defined in a stand-alone class library, it can of course not reference the ViewModelLocator resource it this is not defined in this library or in a library that is referenced by the UC library.

Comment: So yes, it's a standalone UserControl, and there is no reference to the VML, but they are both in the same project !

Comment: The ViewModelLocator and the UserControl reside in the same project?

Comment: Yes, they do. I work on a project that only can use UserControl, but I want to do MVVM for coding. So I need to connect the UC to the VML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that the `ViewModelLocator` class and the `UserControl` reside in the same project/assembly, you could define the `ViewModelLocator` resource in a `ResourceDictionary` that you merge into the `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Global.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="ApplicationVM" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Global.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1">
    <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I was looking for this : `<UserControl.DataContext>` !! Thanks you a lot, spent 2 days on it ^^'

Comment: is there an issue if the resource "Global.xaml" resides in the root folder of the user control and the user control view inside a folder like for i.e. "\GUI\Views"?